# WPF Spell Check Finalizer - Safe Handle has been closed

Tags: c#, wpf, spell-checking

I have a WPF application targeting .NET 4.5.2 (but typically running under 4.6.1) and I've enabled spell checking on a couple of TextBoxes and DataGridTextColumns.  Spell check is enabled via a style depending on what language the user has selected (we currently only support en).  The application and system cultures are all set to en or en-US.  I am not using any custom dictionaries.

Spellcheck is enabled via the following style:

```
<Style TargetType="TextBox">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <MultiDataTrigger>
            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                <Condition Binding="{Binding Source={x:Static Properties:Settings.Default}, Path=Culture}"
                           Value="en" />
                <Condition Binding="{Binding Source={x:Static diagnostics:Debugger.IsAttached}}"
                           Value="False" />
            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
            <Setter Property="SpellCheck.IsEnabled"
                    Value="True" />
        </MultiDataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

(We store the last selected application culture using the built-in ApplicationSettings object, and only save the most generic parent culture.  If the user's system is set to "en-US", we'll just store "en" to simplify things.)

The TextBox is defined in a DataTemplate that is used for TreeViewItems, in case that makes any difference.  Users are more likely to edit the TextBox rather than the DataGrid, so I suspect the issue is related to the TextBox.

On Windows 8 and 10, some users are experience a crash in the spell checker with the following stack trace:

```
System.ObjectDisposedException: Safe handle has been closed
   at System.Threading.WaitHandle.WaitOneNative(SafeHandle waitableSafeHandle, UInt32 millisecondsTimeout, Boolean hasThreadAffinity, Boolean exitContext)
   at System.Threading.WaitHandle.InternalWaitOne(SafeHandle waitableSafeHandle, Int64 millisecondsTimeout, Boolean hasThreadAffinity, Boolean exitContext)
   at System.Threading.WaitHandle.WaitOne(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, Boolean exitContext)
   at System.Windows.Documents.WinRTSpellerInterop.ClearDictionaries(Boolean isDisposeOrFinalize)
   at System.Windows.Documents.WinRTSpellerInterop.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
   at System.Windows.Documents.WinRTSpellerInterop.Finalize()
```

I've searched Google, StackOverflow, and MSDN but can't find any reference to this issue.  I don't know what my users are doing to trigger this case and I have been unable to reproduce it myself.  My logs indicate they are not editing the spellcheck-enabled fields when this happens (in fact, the last editing they did was at least a minute or 2 prior to the exception).  Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: got any thread working going on? no calls to thread.abort?

Comment: Does it happens in the middle of spell checking (when user is entering text), at the end (when user confirm his input) or when view containing elements with spell checking enabled is changing? How exactly you enable spell checking (that "via a style depending ...")?

Comment: @BugFinder No calls to Thread.Abort.  All my stack traces just some idle Threadpool threads.

Comment: There are a lot of references even here about the error, but not specific to spell checkers, only to threads - Im wondering if somehow the spellchecker is active when the textbox and its reference to the checker is being terminated.

Comment: @Sinatr Updated question with my style and some details about what I know about the user operations (last known user edit was at least a minute or 2 prior)

Comment: @BugFinder Possibly.  My TextBoxes are defined in a DataTemplate used in a TreeView, and I tried adding around 1400 TextBoxes so that some of them should get virtualized, including the one at the bottom of the list where the spell checker is detecting a spelling error.  Still cannot reproduce it.  The error doesn't seem to happen on application shutdown, either.

Comment: The SpellCheck.IsEnabled property is a trigger, setting it to *false* causes the class object to be disposed.  Exactly how that interacts so poorly with the finalizer is pretty hard to see, it is not supposed to run.  You need to ask these users what version of .NET they have installed on their machine.  And of course recommend they update when it is old.

Comment: @HansPassant All the users that have reported this issue are running .NET 4.6.1 on either Windows 8.1 or Windows 10 Home.

Comment: I dunno, you'll need help from Microsoft to get this sorted out.  Or tell your users to not attach a debugger, perhaps.  This doesn't exactly get tested often enough, using a trigger isn't a very good idea.

Comment: @HansPassant  My users are not attaching a debugger, I'm using the [Microsoft.Diagnostics.Runtime](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Diagnostics.Runtime) library to log the stack trace of all my threads when an unhandled exception occurs.    I'll post on the MSDN forums and see what I get.

Comment: @BrandonDybala, have you posted this on Connect (under https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/) yet?

Comment: @Vatsan Not yet, hope to get to this over the weekend.

Comment: Please do leave a note here once you've done it. When you post there, it would be very helpful to attach a self-contained and simple (as simple as reasonably possible) project that reproduces the issue. Debug dumps would also be appreciated.

Comment: @Vatsan Unfortunately I have no idea how to reproduce the problem myself.  I've tried reproducing my customers' actions as best I can from the logs I've received, but so far no luck.

Comment: That's ok - please do the best you can. If  you are able to harvest debug dumps from some of your customers, that would be appreciated.

Comment: Well, I WOULD post to Connect, but the site keeps timing out for me today....Will try again later.

Comment: Some progress.  One of my coworkers was able to reproduce the crash once on a Win 8 virtual machine.  And Connect is working again, so I'll post the issue there later today, and hopefully have some more info to consistently reproduce the issue.

Comment: @Vatsan Finally posted the issue to Connect [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/2820480/objectdisposedexception-in-wpf-spell-check-finalizer-windows-8-and-10).  I was also able to get a dump file, but it's too large to post to the Connect issue (1 GB).

Comment: @Vatsan Microsoft responded yesterday that a fix is expected in the next version of .NET.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is resolved in .NET 4.7 (see the "WPF Spellchecker" entry on the [Runtime Changes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt800103(v=vs.110).aspx) page).  Note that NET 4.7 will not install on Windows 10 November Update or earlier.  However, most Windows 10 users should already be on the Anniversary Update by now.

> Starting with the .NET Framework 4.6.1, the spellchecker in WPF applications occasionally throws an ObjectDisposedException during application shutdown.
>
> In the .NET Framework 4.7, the exception is handled gracefully by the runtime, thus ensuring that applications are no longer adversely affected. It should be noted that occasional first-chance exceptions continue to be observed in applications running under a debugger.